# iptables: static ephemeral port maps

Tags: linux, iptables, nat

I have a VPN on my Linux server which does IPv4 NAT, example:

```
iptables -A FORWARD -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -s 10.8.0.0/24 -j ACCEPT
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING  -s 10.8.0.0/24 -o venet0 -j SNAT --to-source 1.2.3.4
```

However I would like to set static ephemeral port ranges per internal 10.8.0.0/24 ip to make logging which client connected to what easier, is this possible with iptables?

For example, ports 1000-2500 will be the ephemeral ports used by 10.8.0.10, 10000-20000 for 10.8.0.20 etc.

I've searched Google but can't find anything.

Answer (score 5):

Check on MASQUERADE target instead of SNAT : it supports the option :

```
--to-ports port[-port]
              This specifies a range of source ports to  use,  overriding  the
              default SNAT source port-selection heuristics (see above).  This
              is only valid if the rule also specifies one  of  the  following
              protocols: tcp, udp, dccp or sctp.
```

I never use it, but test ! But it will only work on tcp, udp. For others, like ICMP, bad luck, there is no port...

Answer (score 0):

I do not think you can control which ports are used for which NAT'd ip's.  However if you have any extra IP's in public space you could have take advantage of that by mapping the ones you want to keep track of:

```
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING  -s 10.8.0.10/32 -o venet0 -j SNAT --to-source 1.2.3.1
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING  -s 10.8.0.20/32 -o venet0 -j SNAT --to-source 1.2.3.2
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING  -s 10.8.0.0/24 -o venet0 -j SNAT --to-source 1.2.3.4
```

Comment: Unfortunately my server only has one public ipv4. i wonder how ISPs  who use carrier grade nat do it?

Comment: They have more IP's to work with.

Comment: 1 public IP would still be shared by at least 2-7 users though, and by using range allocation it simplifies logging

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is very old, so I will share my findings:
According to the iptables manpage at https://linux.die.net/man/8/iptables

```
SNAT

This target is only valid in the nat table, in the POSTROUTING chain. It specifies that the source address of the packet should be modified (and all future packets in this connection will also be mangled), and rules should cease being examined. It takes one type of option:
--to-source ipaddr[-ipaddr][:port-port]
which can specify a single new source IP address, an inclusive range of IP addresses, and optionally, a port range (which is only valid if the rule also specifies -p tcp or -p udp). If no port range is specified, then source ports below 512 will be mapped to other ports below 512: those between 512 and 1023 inclusive will be mapped to ports below 1024, and other ports will be mapped to 1024 or above. Where possible, no port alteration will occur.
In Kernels up to 2.6.10, you can add several --to-source options. For those kernels, if you specify more than one source address, either via an address range or multiple --to-source options, a simple round-robin (one after another in cycle) takes place between these addresses. Later Kernels (>= 2.6.11-rc1) don't have the ability to NAT to multiple ranges anymore.
```

The `--to-source ipaddr[-ipaddr][:port-port]` option allows you to specify ports.
Though I have not tested it, and I will be glad if someone can correct me, I would think now you can use something similar to @chicks answer but with ports.

```
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING  -s 10.8.0.10/32 -o venet0 -j SNAT --to-source 1.2.3.4:1000-1500
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING  -s 10.8.0.20/32 -o venet0 -j SNAT --to-source 1.2.3.4:10000-20000
```

etc.

Ofcourse, this is only valid if the rule also specifies `-p tcp` or `-p udp`.